# Trying to deploy new API to WSO2 server

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to deploy new REST API to a WSO2 server however when I deploy the CAR file which includes the new API it does not appear in the Enterprise Integrator web console.

I am using Integration Studio 7.1.0 and this project, except for testAPI.xml, was created using EI 6.1.0. I have included a project tree for reference:

[image: Project]

The testAPI.xml file also has a question mark icon next to it. Does anybody know what this is? I cannot find any reference from WSO2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this happens when you don't include the API in pom.xml in `xxxx-capp` folder

> Open the file highlighted in the picture attached below and then click the `Select All` button

then save the file redeploy the application that should solve your problem

[image]